# How to control ghost image of the dragged object in HTML5

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

I've noticed that both Chrome and Firefox will render the ghost image of the object being dragged differently depending on the width of the source element: http://jsfiddle.net/Eydnf/1/

```
<div draggable="true" style="width:230px">Example 1</div>
<div draggable="true" style="width:240px">Example 2</div>
```

The first of these DIVs will appear semi-transparent, whereas the second will be rendered with circular gradient transparency. Needless to say that such inconsistency in presentation is very undesirable (not to mention that the second DIV will be hard to see if you grab it by the corner). How can I ensure that the ghost image always renders with uniform transparency, regardless of its width?

Comment: Chrome 35 Mac - They both look exactly the same. Firefox 30 Mac - Both exactly the same. What versions are you using?

Comment: @3rror404 This could be tied to screen's resolution. Unfortunately I do not have access to a Mac, could you try doubling pixel dimensions of both examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to create a consistent Drag and Drop experience I created a jQuery plugin called Dragg.js to be used in place of the HTML5 drag and drop.

```
<div class="draggable" style="width:230px">Example 1</div>
<div class="draggable" style="width:240px">Example 2</div>
<script>
    $('.draggable').dragg();
</script>
```

here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jMLsZ/3/) and here is the [plugin documentation](https://github.com/tonymorello/Dragg)

I hope it helps solving your problem.

Comment: The jQuery + dragg() demo with **milo the dog** helped me to understand how helper element works while dragging :D :D
Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

The following answer might help some, but not everyone.
In my case one of the divs to be dragged was just over the limit where the circular gradient transparancy sets in. The div was 250px and the limit was 249.

I solved it by adding a .dragged class on dragstart to the div with a max-height set to 239px.

In my case it works fine, but I suppose when elements are much larger, the effect won't look good.